# Removing home index from mvc 5 homepage default routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to prevent user to access `abc.com/Home/Index`, instead i want user to be able to access home page via `abc.com` only. I use the following code but not work.

```html
// This code restict user to access abc.com/home/index
// Only allow user to access abc.com/home
routes.MapRoute(
    "OnlyAction",
    "{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } 
);


// This code does not work, I am expecting this code to allow
// user to access home only at abc.com
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",
    "",        
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"} 
);
```

Comment: You cant prevent the user from typing whatever they want in the address bar.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated the description in the code. basically using the first code able to restrict user access to abc.com/home/index and allow user to access home through abc.com or abc.com/home. What i want to achieve is to allow user to access home page through abc.com only

Comment: Maybe you can add it to `routes.IgnoreRoute("Home/Index");`

Comment: @devqon thanks very much

Answer (score 4):

You just need to ignore the URL:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Ignore the alternate path to the home page
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Home/Index");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Then the server will return a 404 not found instead of a page.

Of course, if you wanted to remove all of the alternate paths for the entire application, you would need to remove the default values of the `Default` route, which will make them required.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Ignore the alternate path to the home page
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Home/Index");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Home",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Now you won't be able to access the home page by `/Home/`, either (which is another route that accesses it using the default route).

Of course, the best option is to use the [canonical tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) to ensure no additional routes that may slip through damage your SEO score.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/" />
```

Comment: Hello, It is opening domain.com/Home/About how to open domain.com/About [Without home], but other controller should work e.g. domain.com/Blog/Blog1, domain.com/Account/Login etc